# One time URL/Staging Server

Tags: php, apache, url, centos

I am looking to configure a staging server to show websites to certain people. I need to be able to have the server generate a one time url that the end user can use to view the website, the URL needs to expire after an hour

I am using Centos, Apache, PHP - does anyone know a way of setting this up or if it is even possible?

Example:
User 1 gets a one time URL generated of http://oursite.com/eyfbd68fnvkssp97
User 2 gets a one time URL generated of http://oursite.com/fdsf875vdlnbg2mo

Both the above URL's will load what ever is in the document root of /var/www/html/example.com/httpdocs

Any help on this would be great

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you need to have a PHP script that reads in the token and if it is valid load the content from the location you specified. Otherwise it redirects the user to the normal page.

Comment: To expand on what @thatidiotguy said you need to have a way to tie the one-time URL to a specific user's session, then you need to store that one-time URL, the time it was generated (or time it expires) and the user it is associated with. Then you can write a script that checks for all three of those pieces matching and then loads the contents you want to show them.

Comment: That sounds like what I am after. Because I'm very new to this I may struggle with this one, does anyone have an example of the script i would need to use?